# Menu bar CSS changing with links

Tags: html, css

I have a basic menu bar not unlike the SO one next to the logo (so questions, tags etc.). I have all the styling, but it changes when I add links in. This is hard to explain, so here is my menubar styling:

```
div.menubar ul
{
background-color:#FF0000;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
}
div.menubar li
{
display:inline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.menubar a:hover, div.menubar a:active
{
background-color:#00FF00;//should highlight in green on mouseover
}
div.menubar a:link, div.menubar a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#FF0000;
text-align:center;
padding:6px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

And the menubar code:

```
<div class = "menubar">
<ul>
<li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li><!--does not work-->
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li><!--works-->
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When the link href is something like `#home` the link background changes to green on mouseover. However, when the link href is `home.php`, nothing happens. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try putting `div.menubar a:link, div.menubar a:visited` block before `div.menubar a:hover, div.menubar a:active` block.

Comment: @HemChe thanks for the suggestion; it works but has already been answered :)

Comment: gotta see the answers when i refreshed the page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix, move the hover state to the bottom of your CSS.

In the long term look at the CSS specificity and make sure you're not overriding your hover state with something more 'important'

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mq7n3/

Move this to the bottom

```
div.menubar a:hover, div.menubar a:active
{
background-color:#00FF00;//should highlight in green on mouseover
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it.. You couldn't find the conflicting rule though ;)

Comment: :o) - remove the :link from div.menubar a:link, div.menubar a:visited - this removes the conflict ;o)   http://jsfiddle.net/mq7n3/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.menubar a:hover //this is overridden by below rule, div.menubar a:active //This works
{
    background-color:#00FF00;//should highlight in green on mouseover
}
div.menubar a:link{ //this is overriding div.menubar a:hover
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Try either putting the `:hover` rule after the `:link` rule, removing the `:link` (is it necessary?), or adding in `!important` to the `:hover` rule (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a line of code to get it working

```
div.menubar a:link, div.menubar a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
/*   background-color:#FF0000;           REMOVED  */
text-align:center;
padding:6px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

[See it working](http://jsfiddle.net/eEdvG/)

This works if your anchor tag has a # or not (although no idea why on the original issue)